# highlighting menu on scroll issue - not finding div id with scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I've tried several of the scripts offered in here to highlight menu items on scroll, but for some reason none of them are able to find my `.section id`s.

```
var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
// $currentSection is somewhere to place the section we must be looking at
var $currentSection

// We check the position of each of the divs compared to the windows scroll positon
$sections.each(function(){
  // divPosition is the position down the page in px of the current section we are testing      
  var divPosition = $(this).offset().top;

  // If the divPosition is less than the the currentScroll position the div we are testing has moved above the window edge.
  // the -1 is so that it includes the div 1px before the div leave the top of the window.
  if( divPosition - 1 < currentScroll ){
    // We have either read the section or are currently reading the section so we'll call it our current section
    $currentSection = $(this);

    // If the next div has also been read or we are currently reading it we will overwrite this value again. 
    // This will leave us with the LAST div that passed.
  }

  // This is the bit of code that uses the currentSection as its source of ID
  var id = $currentSection.attr('id');
 $('a').removeClass('active');
 $("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass('active');

   })
 });
});
```

After working on this for a while, I'm thinking it's not able to discover the id of these `div`s for some reason, maybe. I'm able to get it to `addClass` to all of the links, but it won't find the pertinent link with ("[href=#"+id+"]") or a("[href=#"+id+"]") -

I put an `alert(id)` in there and it wouldn't return the id value; it returned 'undefined'...

Here's how my `nav` is built:

```
<nav id="ubermenu-main-111" class="ubermenu ubermenu-nojs ubermenu-main ubermenu-menu-111 ubermenu-responsive ubermenu-responsive-1113 ubermenu-responsive-collapse ubermenu-horizontal ubermenu-transition-slide ubermenu-trigger-hover ubermenu-skin-none  ubermenu-bar-align-full ubermenu-items-align-right">
<ul id="ubermenu-nav-main-111" class="ubermenu-nav">
<li id="menu-item-3328" class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-custom ubermenu-item-object-custom ubermenu-item-3328 ubermenu-item-level-0 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto" >
<a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-text_only" href="#home" tabindex="0" data-ubermenu-scrolltarget="#home">...
```

and a `div.section`:

```
<div class="section mcb-section full-width menuitem " id="home">
```

I got this one from [CodePen](http://codepen.io/clokey2k/pen/jgfFD) but I've tried several from SO too, all with the same results...

Anyone? Very grateful...

Comment: I missed this part of the function -->

$(document).ready(function(){
  // $sections incleudes all of the container divs that relate to menu items.
  var $sections = $('.section');
  
  // The user scrolls
  $(window).scroll(function(){

Comment: You forgot to add that code to the code in your answer? Can you edit your answer to include this code?

Comment: no, i forgot to add that code in my question. that was not an answer. thanks, tho...

Answer (score -1):

this was solved - the function worked when i placed it in a different part of the page.